# How to produce a cosinor model with a linear component in R?

Tags: r, statistics, analysis, trigonometry

Hi StackOverflow community,
I'm not a programmer but a self-taught R user for stats and data visualisation. This is my first question as I have always found posts from other members answered my questions, so thank you and please forgive any etiquette missteps in my question.

I'm trying to create a cosinor model with a linear component in R.

Such that, = {2((−∅)/τ)}++. Where A is the amplitude of the sinusoid, τ is the period set at 24-h, t is time, Ø is the acrophase of the sinusoid, and C and D are the slope and y-intercept of the linear component, respectively. I have looked at the documentation for cosinor.lm{cosinor} and cosinor{psych} but cannot see this capability.

Can a linear component be added to a cosinor model or is there another model that could output significance and values for amplitude, acrophase, slope and y-intercept?

Here is my example data:

```
library(cosinor)
library(ggplot2)

#data frame
time<- c(2, 6, 10, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38)
resp<- c(2.54, 0.13, -0.38, -0.57,  0.11, -0.20, -0.26, -0.62, -0.73)
df<-data.frame(time,resp)

# data fits both linear and cosinor models (but not very well)
cos.model <- cosinor.lm(resp ~ time(time), period=24, data=df)
summary(cos.model)
l.model <- lm(resp ~ time, data=df)
summary(l.model)

#plot with a loess smoother looks like a combination of the models 
#plot to see fit

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = resp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image: linear plot]

```
ggplot.cosinor.lm(cos.model)+
  geom_point(data=df, aes(y=resp, x=time))
```

[image: cosinor plot]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = resp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method ="loess", se = FALSE)
```

[image: loess plot]

If anyone could help me create a model incorporating cosinor and linear components I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance.